# How to upload videos to YouTube using googleapis package in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-api, youtube

I want to upload videos to my YouTube channel from my flutter application. I have implemented YouTube sign-in in the app and acquired the auth tokens and the API key from Google Developer Console that are needed for uploading.

Added [googleapis](https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis/versions/1.0.0) package in the app but couldn't proceed further due to lack of docs on how to use it to upload videos. Any help on how to use this package to upload videos or if there's any other way possible to upload videos is also welcomed.

Comment: There's a plenty of docs about this topic. Have you seen https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert ?

Comment: yes, tried it but wasn't able to make it work. I didn't know how to attach video content in the http request i.e what parameters to use for that and was getting response like "request does not include video content". Can you help me with making this work ?

Answer (score 0):

If you analyze the example Java code in the [YouTube API docs page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert), you should be able to find out, what's needed. They read the file as a stream of data (See [Flutter docs](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.1/dart-io/File-class.html) and [googleapis docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/_discoveryapis_commons/0.2.1/_discoveryapis_commons/Media-class.html) how to achieve this) and pass the raw data into the third parameter of the https request. First parameter is going to be a String of keywords of video details you include, second parameter is going to be the details. If you compare this to the [googleapis docs](https://pub.dev/documentation/googleapis/1.0.0/youtube.v3/VideosResource/insert.html) you'll find out there are similar named classes and parameters to fill your data in and send them to YouTube.

Java/Flutter code uses pretty advanced Java API, so if you are still unable to figure it out, you can make it easier for yourself and use more boring methods. If you switch to Python code on that YouTube API docs page, you see it is just a simple https POST request sending these three parameters in JSON. With that being said, you don't even need to use googleapis for this purpose, but it might be handy as it provides more native implementation.

If you still struggle, please update your question with your code snippet we could look into and tell you, what you are doing wrong.